# PhpStorm - Specified URL is not reachable, caused by:'Request failed with status code 404'

Tags: .htaccess, phpstorm, xdebug, putty, portforwarding

I want to use Xdebug specifically for Step-Debugging feature with PhpStorm. I use Xdebug on my personal apps just fine, without port forwarding. However, my current issue is for an application on servers that I don't have admin privileges to work on php.ini files and the 20-xdebug.ini. I want to use Xdebug by configuring .htaccess to which I "do" have the write permission in the /public directory. I believe that my issue is because we have a server in the middle called a Jump Server, and I think my configs are not right.

X-debug is installed on the web server, but currently disabled. I am enabling it using .htaccess in the /public folder. IT won't enable it on the system due to the server being shared by many developers. I am the only one who uses Xdebug for the app that I am working on.

Xdebug installed.

```
<pre>
developer@****:~$ php --version
PHP 7.2.24-0ubuntu0.18.04.6 (cli) (built: May 26 2020 13:09:11) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) 1997-2018 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.2.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2018 Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v7.2.24-0ubuntu0.18.04.6, Copyright (c) 1999-2018, by Zend Technologies
    with Xdebug v2.6.0, Copyright (c) 2002-2018, by Derick Rethans
</pre>
```

PHP configuration files:

```
<pre>
developer@****:~$ php --ini
Configuration File (php.ini) Path: /etc/php/7.2/cli
Loaded Configuration File:         /etc/php/7.2/cli/php.ini
Scan for additional .ini files in: /etc/php/7.2/cli/conf.d
Additional .ini files parsed:      /etc/php/7.2/cli/conf.d/10-mysqlnd.ini,
...
/etc/php/7.2/cli/conf.d/20-xdebug.ini,
...
</pre>
```

The .htaccess configs:

```
<pre>
developer@****:~$ cat /www/1234-5678/public/.htaccess
zend_extension=xdebug.so
php_flag xdebug.remote_enable=1
php_flag xdebug.remote_autostart on
php_flag xdebug.remote_connect_back=1
php_flag xdebug.remote_port=9000
php_flag xdebug.max_nesting_level=512
php_flag xdebug.remote_host="192.168.10.1"
PHP_flag xdebug.idekey=PHPSTORM
</pre>
```

Installed Xdebug configs:

```
<pre>
developer@****:~$ cat /etc/php/7.2/cli/conf.d/20-xdebug.ini
zend_extension=xdebug.so
</pre>
```

With that set...

This is how I connect to the web server:
PC > PuTTy SSH to connect to the Jump Server > Jump Server SSH to the server by Port # and localhost (ssh -p #### localhost)

I have PuTTY configured:

```
<pre>
Session -
Host Name (or IP address) - fake.jumpserver.com
Port: 22

Connection > SSH > Tunnels
Source Port: 7008
Destination: 192.168.240.100:22008
</pre>
```

Once I open the PuTTy connection, I can use the command to ssh into the local port 7008 (remote port 192.168.240.100:22008).

```
<pre>
developer@lenovo MINGW64 ~
$ ssh -p 7008 localhost
Welcome to Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS (GNU/Linux 5.3.0-1017-aws x86_64)
...
Last login: Fri Jan 15 18:09:05 2021 from 192.168.240.100
developer@****:~$ cd /www/app/1234-5678/public
developer@****:/www/app/1234-5678$ pwd
/www/app/1234-5678/public
</pre>
```

PhpStorm Configurations:

SSH Configs, Test Connection Success!

```
<pre>
Name: Port_22008_SSH

Host: localhost
Port: 7008
Username: developer
Local port: --dynamic
Authentication type: Key pair OpenSSh or PuTTY
Private key file: C:\...\developer\.ssh\id_rsa
Passphrase: *****
</pre>
```

Build, Execution, Deployment:

```
<pre>
Connection -
Name: Port_22008_SFTP

Type: SFTP
SSH Configuration: Port_22008_SSH
Test Connection: Success

Root path: /www/app/1234-56789
Web server URL: https://1234-56789.fakewebsitelink.com

Mappings -

Local path: C:\Users\developer\PhpstormProjects\contracts\1234-5678
Deployment path: /
Web path: /
</pre>
```

Languages & Frameworks

```
<pre>
PHP language Level: 7.2
CLI Interpreter: Port_22008_CLI(7.2.24-0ubuntu0.18.04.6)
<pre>
Name: Port_22008_CLI
SSH Configuration: Port_22008_SSH

PHP Executable: /usr/bin/php
</pre>
Path mappings: Project-root->/www/app/1234-5678
</pre>
```

Now to Validating Debugger Configurations
Languages & Frameworks > Debug

```
<pre>
Path to create validation script: C:\Users\developer\PhpstormProjects\contracts\1234-5678
Deployment Server: Port_22008_SFTP
</pre>
```

Debugger is enabled in Browser

[image]

Idea Log file:

```
    
INFO - eyprovider.OpenSSHKeyV1KeyFile - Keypair is encrypted with: aes256-ctr, bcrypt, [0, 0, 0, 16, 59, -84, -66, -121, 47, 63, 91, -99, -127, 88, -125, -126, -39, -126, 70, -9, 0, 0, 0, 16] 

WARN - net.schmizz.concurrent.Promise - > woke to: Opening `session` channel failed: open failed 

INFO - .channel.direct.SessionChannel - Will request `sftp` subsystem 

INFO - eyprovider.OpenSSHKeyV1KeyFile - Keypair is encrypted with: aes256-ctr, bcrypt, [0, 0, 0, 16, 59, -84, -66, -121, 47, 63, 91, -99, -127, 88, -125, -126, -39, -126, 70, -9, 0, 0, 0, 16] 

INFO - on.PhpRemoteWebServerValidator - Create file '/www/app/1234-5678/_intellij_phpdebug_validator.php' 

INFO - on.PhpRemoteWebServerValidator - Uploading validation script to Port_22008_SFTP completed in 1 sec, 45 ms: 1 file transferred (5.8 kbit/s) 

WARN - lidation.PhpWebServerValidator - Web server validation failed due to: 'Request failed with status code 404' 

INFO - eyprovider.OpenSSHKeyV1KeyFile - Keypair is encrypted with: aes256-ctr, bcrypt, [0, 0, 0, 16, 59, -84, -66, -121, 47, 63, 91, -99, -127, 88, -125, -126, -39, -126, 70, -9, 0, 0, 0, 16] 

INFO - on.PhpRemoteWebServerValidator - Delete file '/www/app/1234-5678/_intellij_phpdebug_validator.php' 

WARN - .AbstractProgressIndicatorBase - This progress indicator is indeterminate, this may lead to visual inconsistency. Please call setIndeterminate(false) before you start progress.
com.intellij.ide.util.DelegatingProgressIndicator.setFraction(DelegatingProgressIndicator.java:78) 

INFO - on.PhpRemoteWebServerValidator - Cleaning up... completed in 138 ms: 1 item deleted
```

Comment: Well, check the access log in your Apache -- what URL is requested and check if such file exists there when such request is happening. You may also check `idea.log` for possible details (`Help | Show Log in...`) -- may need to enable extra logging though: https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/207241115-How-to-Collecting-PhpStorm-WebStorm-debug-Logs

Comment: Hmm. Good suggestion. There isn't much info from the idea.log. It seems there isn't an access log stored on the server at the typical apache2 directory, can't find any and can't do a system-wide search due to permission. Ugh.

Update my post with the idea logs.

Comment: 1) `/www/app/1234-5678/_intellij_phpdebug_validator.php` -- try placing your own file (with just `phpinfo()` in it) with a similar file name and try to call it via browser -- will it work? As I understand it should be called via `https://1234-56789.fakewebsitelink.com/_intellij_phpdebug_validator.php` URL. Maybe it's because it's HTTPS (unlikely but everything is poss)  2) What kind of extra logging have you enabled in PhpStorm? Just deployment? Try enabling Debugging/PHP as well (I hope it will list an URL called as well).